# Inlining of 3D scatterplots fails after upgrading Ipython on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ipython, scatter-plot, enthought

I'm using Ipython as part of the Enthought Python Distribution(EPD) on ubuntu. 
Afer upgrading Ipython from 1.1.0-3 to 2.0.0-1 and pyzmq from 2.2.0-4 to 14.1.1.-1, I encounter some problems. Inlining of 3D scatter 
plots fails due to a signed/unsigned operation within ZMQ.

A code example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import random

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xs,ys, zs = [], [], []
for frame_time in range(100):
    xs.append(random.random())
    ys.append(random.random())
    zs.append(random.random())
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)
```

When trying to run this in an Ipython notebook, I get the following error message:

OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned PY_LONG_LONG

The complete error message:

```
<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Patch3DCollection at 0x9c0560c>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/pylab              /backend_inline.pyc in show(close)
 41     try:
 42         for figure_manager in Gcf.get_all_fig_managers():
 ---> 43             display(figure_manager.canvas.figure)
 44     finally:
 45         show._to_draw = []

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/display.pyc in   display(*objs, **kwargs)
133                 # kwarg-specified metadata gets precedence
134                 _merge(md_dict, metadata)
--> 135             publish_display_data('display', format_dict, md_dict)
136 
137 

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displaypub.pyc in publish_display_data(source, data, metadata)
172         source,
173         data,
--> 174         metadata
175     )
176 

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/zmqshell.pyc in publish(self, source, data, metadata)
 86         self.session.send(
 87             self.pub_socket, u'display_data', json_clean(content),
 ---> 88             parent=self.parent_header, ident=self.topic,
 89         )
 90 

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.pyc in send(self, stream, msg_or_type, content, parent, ident, buffers, track, header, metadata)
644             # use dummy tracker, which will be done immediately
645             tracker = DONE
--> 646             stream.send_multipart(to_send, copy=copy)
647 
648         if self.debug:

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.pyc in send_multipart(self, msg_parts, flags, copy, track)
263         """
264         for msg in msg_parts[:-1]:
--> 265             self.send(msg, SNDMORE|flags, copy=copy, track=track)
266         # Send the last part without the extra SNDMORE flag.
267         return self.send(msg_parts[-1], flags, copy=copy, track=track)

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/socket.so in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5298)()

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/socket.so in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.send (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5146)()

/home/dsg-labuser/EPD/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/message.so in zmq.backend.cython.message.Frame.__cinit__ (zmq/backend/cython/message.c:1645)()

OverflowError: can't convert negative value to unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
```

Afer downgrading to the older version of Ipython, things worked fine again. So there seems to be some problem with Ipython 2.0.0-1 on ubuntu.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Does the pyzmq version change, or just the IPython version? I would expect this to be specific to pyzmq.

Comment: @minrk: I think, IPython as well as pyzmq had just been updatet when this problem occured.

Comment: can you check the test output of `nosetests zmq`?

Comment: What is the value of `sys.maxint`?

Comment: And what ubuntu version?

Comment: @ minrk: as sys.maxint I am given 2147483647, ubuntu version is ubuntu 12.04.3 lts

Comment: Thanks, I found the bug. It's in pyzmq [14.0,14.2) on 32b Python. Upgrading pyzmq to latest, or using 64b Python will fix it, as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in pyzmq ≥ 14.0 on 32b Python. It should be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/pull/534), which should be released in pyzmq-14.2 in the next few days. Immediate workarounds include:

- use 64b Python, if possible
- use pyzmq 13
- manually apply the above patch and install pyzmq